# how to create dynamic links using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Can't really write that much in vba, just used recording and subsequent edits so far - please be gentle :)

I'm trying to get a 'dynamic' link between file A and a file whose name I want to specify in a cell.

so far I created a link to a file and tried to create a macro that would modify it (i.e. the source file specified in the link), based on a value given in a cell. Failed miserably... any advice?

```
Sub Macro1()

    Worksheets("aaa").Activate

    Dim FTW As String

    FTW = Cells(1, "A").Value

    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:= _
        "FTW", NewName:= _
        "FTW", Type:=xlExcelLinks

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ChangeLink() 
Dim OldLink As String 
Dim NewLink As String 
Dim wks As Worksheet 
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("aaa")

OldLink = "SPECIFY OLD HERE"
NewLink = wks.Range("A1").Value 
ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=OldLink, NewName:=NewLink, Type:=xlExcelLinks 
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad it is working for you @AndrzejK please accept as an answer :-)